# How to specifiy prompt location in terminal?

Tags: command-line, settings, prompt

I am using GNOME 3.2 and my problem is that while working on terminal my prompt is usually at the bottom of screen. As GNOME notifications keep popping up on new mail, chat or song change, it becomes hard to work at the lowest line of terminal.

Is there any way I can set prompt location few lines above the last line in the Terminal, so that I don't have to run `clear` every time?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempt to prevent some number of lines near the bottom of the Terminal window from being used, you might want to instead simply resize the Terminal window to whatever best serves your needs. You can put your mouse pointer over the lower-right corner of the Terminal window (or, really, over anywhere on the lower edge) until the mouse pointer changes to a different icon representing resizing. Then click and hold, and drag the border upwards until the window is however small you want it.

To make it so that all Terminals will be of a custom height (and, if you like, width) when you start them, go to `Edit` > `Profile Preferences` in Terminal. A window with the title `Editing Profile "Default"` will come up (or it will give a different profile name, if you're using a named custom profile). In the `General` tab (which should already be showing), check the box labeled `Use custom default terminal size`. Then you can decrease the number of `rows` from 24 to whatever you like.

If your Terminal window is maximized, so that it takes up the whole screen and cannot be resized, then you should restore it to normal size (using the buttons on the window decorator, i.e., on the bar at the top of the window). Then you can either move it to a different location on the screen so that it is more convenient, or resize it as described above.

Comment: @ Eliah Kagan: You are right in a way. But for that I have to resize it everytime I use my terminal. Also it is difficult to concentrate when you are working in the last line of window.

Comment: @AtulKakrana Good point about how you'd have to manually resize each time if you were following my instructions; I just edited my post to explain how to change the default Terminal size. As for your second point, that probably means that the answer I've proposed will not be suitable for you (though you might try changing your desktop wallpaper or background color to something less distracting, I understand that may not be adequate for your needs). Hopefully someone else will know how to do what you are asking (then you can accept their answer). And if I find out how, I'll edit my post again.

Comment: @Elian: Thanks for taking time and writing down detailed instructions about resizing terminal. I actually know all those options. But the problem is that I use smaller size (set in terminal preferences) when I work on multiple things and full size when only working on terminal. There must be some way to configure prompt location. If I find any answer I post it here.

Comment: @AtulKakrana You might have better luck searching for information about this if phrase the problem in different terms. Presumably, what you want really has nothing to do with the `bash` prompt at all. My understanding is that what you really want to do is to make the Terminal start scrolling down when text is written to some row higher than the final row.

Comment: @Elian: You nailed it right will file a new post

Comment: @AtulKakrana You might want to instead edit this question to clarify this. (The answer I gave is based on that understanding of your question, so it wouldn't be rendered irrelevant or anything, though as I've said I do hope somebody else is able to provide you a better one than I  have.)

Answer (score 1):

I use text editors a lot so want my terminal to be full screen height but I also don't want the prompt at the bottom.

I recently figured out an approach using the terminal's support for a character that goes "up" and bash's support to run a command before printing the primary prompt. I hope it works for other people. You'd put the following in your .bash_profile (merging with other code you have setting the prompt (PS1) ).

```
function proml {
local UP="\033[F"
local CL="\033[0J"
PS1="\$ "
export PROMPT_COMMAND_SPACE="\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$UP$CL"
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"$PROMPT_COMMAND_SPACE\""
}
proml
```

Put N newlines (`\n`) and N `$UP` variables to get N blank lines at the bottom.

And then keep this stuff in your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try using guake**, at least as a work-around.  It has an option, "**Main Window Height**" which allows you to **vertically adjust how much screen is utilized**.  This way you can prevent the prompt from ever being under your notifications. The option stays saved, **you won't need to resize everytime**.

[image: Guake has some cool features, like a single button hotkey]

- Install guake via the terminal with `sudo apt-get install guake`
- Then type `guake-prefs` to bring up the preferences dialogue.
- Find the "Main Window Height" scrollbar at the bottom of the menu and adjust to suit your needs.

[image]